# Update RoutingTable of IPv6 in INET Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

how can I update the IPv6 routing table of my mobile node when I disassociated from an AP.
What is the usual way to do that? I guess the interface table should also be updated.

Comment: can you provide some code about the structure of your routing table?

Comment: I'm using the default implementation of IPv6RoutingTable.h of INET 2.991